# Lifting force applied to an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, buoyancy, fluid-statics, lift

The question is as following:

> Identical $K$, $L$ and $M$ containers have liquids with densities $d$,
>   $2d$ and $3d$ respectively.
>
> A solid object with density $d$ is being dropped in all of them one
>   after one.
>
> The lifting forces the liquids apply to the solid object are $F_{K}$,
>   $F_{L}$ and $F_{M}$.
>
> Compare $F_{K}$, $F_{L}$ and $F_{M}$.

My reply was **They are all equal** since no liquid has lower density than the object and therefore the object won't sink and the lifting force should be equal to the weight of the solid object. But the answer sheet suggests it is $F_{K} > F_{L} > F_{M}$.

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the answer sheet! The OP is correct. The object droped into the two heavy liquids will float. It  will therefore not dispace its own volume of liquid, but only its own mass.  If the object were forced below the surface in te denser liquids, then  the uplift would be greatest in the densest fluid but "dropped" implies that the object is not being forcibly submerged.

Comment: And in the case of submerging OP would still be closer than the given answer to correct.

Comment: Yes, in all three cases the buoyancy forces are equal to the weight of the object, and therefore identical.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct in thinking that the **net** forces are all the same (IE. nothing is moving)

$$ F_b - F_g = 0$$

Though, you should be careful when evaluating: 
$$ \ F_b - F_g = \rho_{fluid} \cdot V_{fluid} - \rho_{object} \cdot V_{object}.$$

The densities and volumes are not measuring the same thing. And because the fluids all have different densities, the buoyant forces in each case are different. The question asks you to rank the **buoyant** forces $F_b$.

Where,

> $$F_b = m_{f} \cdot g, \ \ \ \ \ F_g = m_{ob} \cdot g, \ \ \ \ \ m_{f}= \rho_{f} \cdot V $$

\begin{align} F_{b1} &= dVg \\ F_{b2} &= 2dVg \\ F_{b3} &= 3dVg  \end{align}

---

Since we know that $F_g$ isn't changing in each scenario, that means that the buoyant forces must be different from one another:

> \begin{align} F_{b1} &= \frac{m_{ob}}{dV} \\ F_{b2} &= \frac{m_{ob}}{2dV} \\ F_{b3} &= \frac{m_{ob}}{3dV}  \end{align}

So, the answer sheet was right.

And this makes sense if you think about the core assumption we made: the object is floating (IE. it's not allowed to move). The less water you displace, the more the buoyant force has to "contribute" to keep you from not moving.

*From Archimedes Principle (wiki):*

> Take a rock that weighs $10$ units.
>   Put it in some water, say it displaces $3$ units.
>   The buoyant force is $10-3= 7$ units
>   Take the same rock at $10$, say it now displaces $4$, and the new buoyant force is $6$.

Notice that the more water being displaced, the less the buoyant force.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53224/discussion-on-answer-by-aiden-murphy-lifting-force-applied-to-an-object).